# How to distribute li elements equally when html don't have whitespaces?

Tags: html, css

I read this article [Almost complete guide to flexbox (without flexbox)](https://kyusuf.com/post/almost-complete-guide-to-flexbox-without-flexbox), and I've try to use "space-between", I have code like this:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}
ul:after {
  content: "";
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>Foo</li><li>Bar</li><li>Baz</li></ul>
<ul>
<li>Foo</li>
<li>Bar</li>
<li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

`<li>`'s in first `<ul>` is not distributed correctly because `<li>` don't have whitespace at the end of `<li>` tags, is it possible to have distribution using `text-align: justify` when html is one line without whitespace?  Is it possible without flexbox?

I've tried to add `ul li:after` but that didn't work.

Comment: somthing like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tarqggjm/1/)

Comment: @Leothelion it create space after Baz, the last element should be aligned to the right.

Comment: sorry to say but a method with child. if you like then check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tarqggjm/2/)

Comment: @Leo this is close enough but if you add more elements the space between them wont be the same

Comment: @phobia82 no..i tried to add and space was same..how much element you have added?

Comment: oops got your point. you are talking about first and last child?

Answer (score 0):

In this case `text-align: justify` is not appropriate because first of all you need to allow width for list item, then `text-align` will work. You can use width in % and after that `text-align` to align text.

```css
ul {
  width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul li {
    float:left;
    line-height:37px;
    height:100%;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 33.33%;
  background: red;

}
ul li span{
 background: blue;
 display: block;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>Foo</li><li>Bar</li><li>Baz</li></ul>
<ul>
<li><span>Foo</span></li>
<li><span>Bar</span></li>
<li><span>Baz</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will not create equal distribution, you have space after last li.

Comment: why fix width??

Comment: @jcubic, I added extra to `span` tag and bg color. Where is the space?

Comment: @Leothelion, there is no fixed with, it's `%`

Comment: @RuhulAmin Baz should be aligned to the right and the space between should be equal.

Comment: Also number of elements may change.