# How to add whitespace after each element created by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to do equal distribution of elements from this question [How to distribute li elements equally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972768/how-to-distribute-li-elements-equally) I'm using angular with jade:

```
ul
  li(ng-repeat="item in items") {{item.name}}
```

but ng-repeat don't create newlines after each elements and `text-align: justify` don't work. Is it possible to inject newline or space after each li in html returned by ng-repeat?

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IvwZ77TFE7GkBBpYoUfm?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fissio solution almost work, I just need to add this css:

```
br {
  display: none;
}
```

and it work. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7D7pssbcEFHTCysxPng8?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points):

```
ul
  li(ng-repeat-start="step in workflow.data.steps", class="{{step.status|lowercase}}", ng-class="{selected: step.caption == workflow.data.step.caption}")
    //ng-style="{width: (100/(workflow.data.steps.length > 6 ? 6 : workflow.data.steps.length)) + '%'}"
    div
      span.box {{step.caption}}
      span.status(ng-show="workflow.data.steps.loaded") {{step.status}}
      span.status(ng-hide="workflow.data.steps.loaded") ...
  br(ng-repeat-end)
```

Comment: This will create html tag after each li and I want literal newline or space in html.

Comment: Oh - can't you just use css like `margin-bottom:10px` or something? Or can you create a plunker to demonstrate?

Comment: Your solution almost work after all, I just needed to add `br { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
<li ng-repeat="your code">
<span ng-if="!$first || !$last"><br></span>{{item.name}}
</li>
```

if it is not a first and last item then it will not add "br" . otherwise it will add a break

Comment: You can even simplify this by using `ng-if"$middle"` :)

Comment: No there is not three elements . elements can be more then three

Comment: if the number of items is three then ng-if="$middle " will works fine

Comment: No, according to the docs it says that every element besides of first and last is considered as $middle. Check this plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/SHCJCA8OgQITaKG3wke7?p=preview