# How to add whitespace between tags in jade compiled by webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, pug

I have angular template that look like this:

```
ul
  li(ng-repeat-start="item in items") {{item.name}}
  br(ng-repeat-end)
```

is it possible to have space between li and br or newline character? I have this:

```
{ test: /\.jade$/, loader: 'raw!jade-html' }
```

in `module.loaders` in `webpack.config.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
ul.
  <li ng-repeat-start="item in items">{{item.name}}</li> <br ng-repeat-end/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use CSS to have gap in between `li` and `br`, something like,

```
ul > li + br {
   margin-top: 20px
}
```

Comment: I need to have real whitespace in order to have this css work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40972768/how-to-distribute-li-elements-equally